# Automatic vacuum of table "cloudsqladmin.public.heartbeat"

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

We're experiencing some constant outages in our back-end that seem to correlate with peaks of high CPU usage for our Cloud SQL Postgres instance (v9.6)

[image: postgres instance cpu usage]

Taking a look to the `cloudsql.googleapis.com/postgres.log`, those high CPU peaks seems to also correlate to when the database is running an automatic vacuum of table `cloudsqladmin.public.heartbeat`

[image: postgres logs]

We haven't found any documentation on what this table is and why is running autovacuum so often (our own tables doesn't seem to be affected by it).

Is this normal? Should we tune the values for the autovacuum? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your graphs there is no correlation between the CPU and the cloudsqladmin.public.heartbeat autovacuum.

Lets start by what the cloudsqladmin.public.heartbeat table is, this is a table used by the Cloud SQL High Availability process, this is better explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#failover-process):

> Each second, the primary instance writes to a system database as a
>   heartbeat signal.

So the table is used internally to keep track of your instance's health. The autovacuum is triggered based on the [doc](https://www.netiq.com/documentation/cloud-manager-2-5/ncm-install/data/vacuum.html) David shared.

Now, if the Vacuum process generated the CPU spike, you would see the spike every minute/second.

So, straight answers to your questions:

Is this normal? : Yes, the autovacuum and the cloudsqladmin.public.heartbeat table are completely normal from a Cloud SQL internal perspective, they should not impact in any way the Instance.

Should we tune the values for the autovacuum? : No need for that, as mentioned, this process is not the one impacting the CPU Instance, you can hide the similar logs including "cloudsqladmin.public.heartbeat" and analyze the ones left on the time the Spike was presented.

It is worth looking at the backup processes triggered too (there could be one on the same time) Cloud SQL > Instance Details > Backups, but of course, that's a different topic than the one described here :) .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recommendation that seems very relevant to your situation: https://www.netiq.com/documentation/cloud-manager-2-5/ncm-install/data/vacuum.html

Comment: Thank you! while it's useful to know that the autovacuum settings can be changed on per table basis, this doesn't explain anything about what `cloudsqladmin.public.heartbeat` is and why it needs autovacuum so often. Note that we don't have access to the `cloudsqladmin` db, it comes with the Cloud SQL instance, but we cannot read it nor change its settings.

Comment: The CPU chart just shows one spike, not a spike every 5 minutes.

Comment: @jjanes that's true, but every time there is a spike there is an auto-vacuum running (not the other way around). It could be casual, but I think is still worth exploring why that auto-vacuum is happening.